# XUnit - Assert.DoesNotThrow with Particular Exception Type Only

Tags: c#, xunit.net

Is it possible to use `Assert.DoesNotThrow` with a particular exception type?

For example how do I verify that a method call is not throwing `NullReferenceExceptions` specifically but it may throw `NotSupportedException` which I don't care about. ?

Comment: I think that `Assert.DoesNotThrow` comes from NUnit or XUnit, not from FakeItEasy.

Comment: 'Assert.DoesNotThrow' it self is not there in the new release of XUnit https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/188. I'm still trying to understand the justification behind this decision.

Comment: Brad: "Every single line of code is an implicit "does not throw", because if it throws, then the test fails."

Answer (score 8):

There's a pattern null checking in xUnit.

```
var ex = Record.Exception(...);
Assert.Null(ex);
```

It's bit late; however, hope it helps you :).